# Escape & in Yaml

Tags: json, shell, kubernetes, yaml

I've been trying several options to escape  `&` in a kubernetes deployment manifest (  `"command": ["sh","-c","nohup /bin/ecr-token-refresh \&;sleep 10; exit 0"]` with no luck yet.

```
  pod.beta.kubernetes.io/init-containers: '[
       {
        "name": "token-refresh-prestart",
        "image": "{{ .Values.images.ecrrefresh }}",
        "command": ["sh","-c","nohup /bin/ecr-refresh-token \&;sleep10; exit 0"] ,
        "volumeMounts": [
                    {
                        "name": "prod-b-spin-refresh-config",
                        "mountPath": "/opt/config/ecr-token-refresh",
                        "readOnly": false
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "password-volume",
                        "mountPath": "/opt/passwords",
                        "readOnly": false
                    }
                ]
       }
    ]'
```

Answer (score 2):

you can add command like this.

```
command:
  - "sh"
  - "-c"
  - >
    nohup /bin/ecr-refresh-token &
    sleep 10
    exit 0
```

Is there a reason why your putting this in the background?

Comment: Basically the application is a server that continues to run indefinitely. I want to it run only for a few seconds (writes a file that is needed in the actual containers) and terminate as it is going to be an initContainer

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent is

```
nohup /bin/ecr-refresh-token \\\u0026
```

But the problem is that there is no way to run the process in the background as part of the manifest. You can do that if you manually kc exec into the pod